# jquery slider that can have unlimited tabs

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a slider which can support many tabs(unlimited) something like this:

http://webtalkradio.net/

it's flash btw. i'm looking for a jquery slider.

If you know, do share with me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html

the limit that the container can hold is based on the max limit that a DOM will allow for size. I believe it's 20000em. So..however many objects you can fit into that. Very well documented and supported; you can find vertical and horizontal versions of this. I use a site that utilizes both horizontal and vertical scrolling together to make beautiful fluid transitions on pages and create very unique effects that I haven't seen before.